# Windows Forms Application Crash After Starting To Use SQLite-net-pcl only on some computers

Tags: c#, winforms, crash, sqlite-net-pcl

I used OLEDB in a C# Windows Forms Application but then I decided to change everything to SQLite-net-pcl because it was easier for me. 
After I finished everything, made sure there was no bugs - it works only in 2 out of 7 computers. What can I do? 
I've seen that people use SQLite-NET, is it the same? Can it work?

I've tried restarting the computers, re-building. I also tried to open a file that doesn't contain anything associated with the SQL-net-pcl reference and it worked.

It crashes right when there is a file with SQL (main file).

Comment: Do you have the exception message or  some log ? I think you can use Unhandled Exception(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=netframework-4.8) to catch your exception. You can find your crash problem and modify it.

Comment: There is no exception message because I start it on other devices with the exe file...